# Swift : How can I make a uipickerview that shows the date and time frame

Tags: ios, swift, uipickerview

I can show the time and change the time intervals but I don’t know how to get a time frame with the dates like the photo below unless I hard code it. 
Trying to avoid using any cocoapods if I don’t have to. Right now I'm hard coding it, but only the time, I can't get the date in without having another `UIPicker`.

Code relating to the `UIPickerView` in question:

```
private var deliveryTimesPicker = UIPickerView()
private var deliveryTimes = ["10 AM - 11 AM", "11 AM - 12 PM", "12 PM - 1 PM", "1 PM - 2 PM", "2 PM - 3 PM", "3 PM - 4 PM", "4 PM - 5 PM", "5 PM - 6 PM", "6 PM - 7 PM", "7 PM - 8 PM", "8 PM - 9 PM", "9 PM - 10 PM", "10 PM - 11 PM"]
private var selectedDeliveryTime = 0

override func viewDidLoad() {
    ...
    self.deliveryTimeTF.text = self.deliveryTimes.first!

    self.doneToolbar.barStyle = .default
    self.doneToolbar.isTranslucent = true
    self.doneToolbar.isUserInteractionEnabled = true
    self.doneToolbar.setItems([
        UIBarButtonItem(title: "Cancel", style: .plain, target: self, action: #selector(self.dismissKeyboard)),
        UIBarButtonItem(barButtonSystemItem: .flexibleSpace, target: nil, action: nil),
        UIBarButtonItem(title: "Done", style: .done, target: self, action: #selector(self.pickerViewDone))
        ], animated: true)
    self.doneToolbar.sizeToFit()

    self.deliveryTimesPicker.delegate = self
    self.deliveryTimesPicker.dataSource = self
    self.deliveryTimesPicker.tag = 0
    self.deliveryTimesPicker.selectRow(self.selectedDeliveryTime, inComponent: 0, animated: true)
    self.deliveryTimeTF.inputView = self.deliveryTimesPicker
    self.deliveryTimeTF.inputAccessoryView = self.doneToolbar
}


@objc func pickerViewDone() {
    if self.deliveryTimeTF.isEditing {
        self.deliveryTimeTF.text = self.deliveryTimes[self.selectedDeliveryTime]
    }
    dismissKeyboard()
}

extension RequestViewController: UIPickerViewDelegate {
    func pickerView(_ pickerView: UIPickerView, titleForRow row: Int, forComponent component: Int) -> String? {
        if pickerView.tag == 0 {
            self.selectedDeliveryTime = row
            return self.deliveryTimes[self.selectedDeliveryTime]
        }
    }

    func pickerView(_ pickerView: UIPickerView, didSelectRow row: Int, inComponent component: Int) {
        if pickerView.tag == 0 {
             self.selectedDeliveryTime = row
        }
    }

}
```

How mine is:

[image]

How I want it to be (color theme isn't important just the function of it):
[image: From skipthedishes app]

Comment: Whats the code you have tried and what are the results you are getting form it?

Comment: @MwcsMac added the code

Comment: Any you trying to find a way to calculate an array of time ranges?

Answer (score 0):

Based on your code, you can use keyboard view like this:

```
protocol DeliveryTimeKeyboardDelegate  {
    func closeKeyboard()
    func validate(deliveryTime: (Date, Int)?)
}

class DeliveryTimeKeyboard: UIStackView {
    let datePickerView = UIDatePicker()
    let hourPickerView = UIPickerView()
    var delegate: DeliveryTimeKeyboardDelegate?
    private var deliveryTimes = ["10 AM - 11 AM", "11 AM - 12 PM", "12 PM - 1 PM", "1 PM - 2 PM", "2 PM - 3 PM", "3 PM - 4 PM", "4 PM - 5 PM", "5 PM - 6 PM", "6 PM - 7 PM", "7 PM - 8 PM", "8 PM - 9 PM", "9 PM - 10 PM", "10 PM - 11 PM"]

    var cancelButton: UIBarButtonItem?
    var clearButton: UIBarButtonItem?
    var doneButton: UIBarButtonItem?

    var deliveryTime: (Date, Int) {
        let day = datePickerView.date
        let period = hourPickerView.selectedRow(inComponent: 0)
        return (day, period)
    }

    var toolbar: UIToolbar {
        let toolBar = UIToolbar()

        toolBar.barStyle = UIBarStyle.default
        toolBar.isTranslucent = true
        toolBar.tintColor = UIColor.black
        toolBar.sizeToFit()

        let cancelButton = UIBarButtonItem(title: "Cancel", style: UIBarButtonItemStyle.plain, target: self, action: #selector(self.cancelAction))
        let clearButton = UIBarButtonItem(barButtonSystemItem: .trash, target: self, action: #selector(self.clearAction))
        let doneButton = UIBarButtonItem(title: "Done", style: UIBarButtonItemStyle.plain, target: self, action: #selector(self.doneAction))
        let spaceButton = UIBarButtonItem(barButtonSystemItem: UIBarButtonSystemItem.flexibleSpace, target: nil, action: nil)
        self.cancelButton = cancelButton
        self.clearButton = clearButton
        self.doneButton = doneButton

        toolBar.setItems([cancelButton, spaceButton, clearButton, spaceButton, doneButton], animated: false)
        toolBar.isUserInteractionEnabled = true
        return toolBar
    }

    convenience init() {
        self.init(frame:  CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: 1, height: 216))
        addArrangedSubview(datePickerView)
        addArrangedSubview(hourPickerView)
        datePickerView.datePickerMode = .date
        hourPickerView.delegate = self
        hourPickerView.dataSource = self

        axis = .horizontal
    }


    @objc func cancelAction() {
        delegate?.closeKeyboard()
    }

    @objc func clearAction() {
        delegate?.validate(deliveryTime: nil)
    }

    @objc func doneAction() {
        delegate?.validate(deliveryTime: deliveryTime)
    }
}

extension DeliveryTimeKeyboard: UIPickerViewDelegate {
    func pickerView(_ pickerView: UIPickerView, titleForRow row: Int, forComponent component: Int) -> String? {
        guard row < deliveryTimes.count else { return nil }
        return deliveryTimes[row]
    }
}
extension DeliveryTimeKeyboard: UIPickerViewDataSource {
    func numberOfComponents(in pickerView: UIPickerView) -> Int {
        return 1
    }

    func pickerView(_ pickerView: UIPickerView, numberOfRowsInComponent component: Int) -> Int {
        return deliveryTimes.count
    }
}

class ViewController: UIViewController {

    @IBOutlet weak var inputDeliveryTime: UITextField!

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        let deliveryTimeKeyboard = DeliveryTimeKeyboard()
        inputDeliveryTime.inputView = deliveryTimeKeyboard
        inputDeliveryTime.inputAccessoryView = deliveryTimeKeyboard.toolbar
    }
}
```

Comment: What does this have to do with the question?

Comment: Agreed. I want my uipicker to look or have similar actions to the image I showed with red save button.

Comment: You want a date selector next to a "period" selector with a cancel button and a save button. This code do that. Desgin is different but you said "color theme isn't important just the function of it".

Answer (score 0):

> I don’t know how to get a time frame with the dates like the photo below unless I hard code it.

Then you should read up on `Date`, `DateInterval`, `DateComponents`, etc. Pick a starting date and use it to generate a list of pairs of start and end dates. Here's some pseudocode:

```
let start = Date()
var timeframes = (Date,Date)[]
for i in (0..9) {
    let t1 = Date(timeInterval: (i * secondsBetweenStarts) since:start)
    let t2 = Date(timeInterval: timeFrameDuration since:t1)
    let timeframe = (t1, t2)
    timeframes.append(timeframe)
}
```

You'll have to fill in values for `secondsBetweenStarts` and `timeFrameDuration` of course. And there are plenty of other ways to construct dates -- for example, using date components would make it easy to create periods that start and end on hour boundaries. Anyway, the idea is to just create an array of start and end times. From there it should be easy to generate a list of strings that describe those timeframes, and you can use that list of strings in the picker.

Answer (score 0):

Always avoid using tags to identify things, the picker will be the right one.

This approach return two items on the picker for the user to select from, you only need to adjust the first date with the time you want it to start from. The user will be able to select the delivery date and the delivery time, when the picker value changes the code will provide you the selected date with the delivery time range, you could also use the logic on the didSelectRow on your pickerViewDone function using the Picker var (deliveryTimesPicker) as source.

The only thing that I didn't do was checking the optionals values, and you also need to make sure the picker has at least two components (picker.numberOfComponents) and if the dates are generated properly.

```
let deliveryDateDayFormatter = DateFormatter()
let deliveryDateTimeFormatter = DateFormatter()

let deliveryDateDays: [String] = {
    deliveryDateDayFormatter.dateFormat = "E, d MMM y"
    deliveryDateTimeFormatter.dateFormat = "h:mm a"

    var deliveryDate = Date()
    var deliveryDateDaysArray: [String] = []
    deliveryDateDaysArray.append("Today")

    for dateIndex in 0 ... 8 {
        deliveryDate = Calendar.current.date(byAdding: .day, value: dateIndex, to: deliveryDate)!

        let deliveryDateDay = deliveryDateDayFormatter.string(from: deliveryDate)

        deliveryDateDaysArray.append("\(deliveryDateDay)")
    }
    return deliveryDateDaysArray
}()


let deliveryDateTimes: [String] = {
    deliveryDateDayFormatter.dateFormat = "E, d MMM y"
    deliveryDateTimeFormatter.dateFormat = "h:mm a"

    var deliveryDate = Date()
    var deliveryDateTimesArray: [String] = []
    deliveryDateTimesArray.append("ASAP")

    for _ in 0 ... 8 {
        let deliveryDateTimeFrom = deliveryDateTimeFormatter.string(from: deliveryDate)

        deliveryDate = Calendar.current.date(byAdding: .minute, value: 30, to: deliveryDate)!

        let deliveryDateTimeTo = deliveryDateTimeFormatter.string(from: deliveryDate)

        deliveryDateTimesArray.append("\(deliveryDateTimeFrom) - \(deliveryDateTimeTo)")
    }
    return deliveryDateTimesArray
}()

func numberOfComponents(in pickerView: UIPickerView) -> Int {
    return 2
}

func pickerView(_ pickerView: UIPickerView, numberOfRowsInComponent component: Int) -> Int {
    var pickerComponents: [[String]] = []

    pickerComponents.append(deliveryDateDays)
    pickerComponents.append(deliveryDateTimes)

    return pickerComponents[component].count
}

func pickerView(_ pickerView: UIPickerView, didSelectRow row: Int, inComponent component: Int) {
    let dateFormatter = DateFormatter()
    dateFormatter.dateFormat = "E, d MMM y h:mm a"

    let selectedDeliveryDayIndex = pickerView.selectedRow(inComponent: 0)
    let selectedDeliveryTimeIndex = pickerView.selectedRow(inComponent: 1)

    let selectedDeliveryDay = deliveryDateDays[selectedDeliveryDayIndex]
    let selectedDeliveryTime = deliveryDateTimes[selectedDeliveryTimeIndex]

    let fullTimeRange = selectedDeliveryTime.components(separatedBy: " - ")

    let timeFrom   = fullTimeRange[0]
    let timeTo = fullTimeRange[1]

    let selectedDateStringFrom = "\(selectedDeliveryDay) \(timeFrom)"
    let selectedDateStringTo = "\(selectedDeliveryDay) \(timeTo)"

    //Delivery date from
    let selectedDateTimeFrom = dateFormatter.date(from: selectedDateStringFrom)!

    //Delivery date to
    let selectedDateTimeTo = dateFormatter.date(from: selectedDateStringTo)!

    //Delivery range
    var deliveryDate = (selectedDateTimeFrom,selectedDateTimeTo)

    print(selectedDateTimeFrom)
    print(selectedDateTimeTo)

    print(deliveryDateDays)
    print(deliveryDateTimes)
}

func pickerView(_ pickerView: UIPickerView, titleForRow row: Int, forComponent component: Int) -> String? {
    var pickerComponents: [[String]] = []

    pickerComponents.append(deliveryDateDays)
    pickerComponents.append(deliveryDateTimes)

    return pickerComponents[component][row]
}
```